# Instantiating ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory via JNDI

Tags: activemq-classic, jndi

I have got JNDI working to lookup a standard ActiveMQ connection factory, however I am having problems updating this to create an ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory, whereby I can then programatically set keystore/truststore information.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
Hashtable<String, String> environmentVariables = new Hashtable<String, String>();
environmentVariables.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
environmentVariables.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ssl:/...");

initialContext = new InitialContext(environmentVariables);

QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = initialContext.lookup("QueueConnectionFactory");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ah and you want to use the pure JMX API? And thus can't type cast to ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory? And what AMQ version do you sue?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I can only cast to Queue/Topic or ActiveMQ ConnectionFactory and not the SSL variant that I require.

Is there an alternative JMS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no mechanism for doing this via JNDI.. so you have to create it programatically.